# User agreement banner in SSH secure shell service

Tags: ssh, banner

I am looking for some help to display a login banner when connecting to a remote server using SSH to display a message and then prompt the User with "yes or no". Only upon entering "yes" , the User should be prompted to enter the password during SSH.

I know login banners can be configured using /etc/issue.net and then uncommenting the line Banner in /etc/ssh/sshd_config followed by restarting SSH. However, If i want additionally SSH to prompt for accepting the policy banner after displaying the banner, how do i go about it ?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to require the user to agree to whatever policy you want before issuing a password in the first place? This just feels like an unnecessary hurdle to logging in for presumably authorized users.

Comment: I understand. But still only if they accept by saying "yes" we want to pursue further

Comment: I think the second sentence is based on misunderstandings of how SSH works. AFAICT the ssh server can't display anything to the user until *after* the user has been authenticated. (Also, if the user uploads a public key to their `authorized_keys` file, they will never be prompted to enter a password.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /usr/share/agreement.txt
read -p "Do you accept? (y/n) " choice
if [[ $choice = y ]] ; then
        /bin/bash
fi
```

Create the file `/usr/share/agreement.txt` with the contents of your agreement and make the script executable (using `chmod +x`).

Then edit `/etc/passwd` and set the command to run to the path of this script (for example `/usr/share/agreement.sh`).

Comment: Thank you Louis. However, in /etc/passwd after the User accepts the agreement, it should still go and authenticate the User based on the username/password. In the above, when you enter "yes" , why do we have /bin/bash ?

Comment: Also, since /etc/passwd contains entry in the form : Name:Password: UserID:PrincipleGroup:Gecos: HomeDirectory:Shell , where will we set the command to run the path agreement.sh

Comment: Shell can be [any command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/), so just replace `/bin/bash` by the full path of the script.

Comment: Which user will be this ? This "yesOrno" prompt should happen before the password is prompted for any User

Comment: You have to change it for every user you want to see it. It shows after the user is logged in, but if they don't answer 'y' the connection will be closed.

Comment: "Only upon entering 'yes' , the User should be prompted to enter the password during SSH." Anything executed on the server would be *after* the user has already logged in.

Comment: I want it to be displayed BEFORE the user is logged in. before the password prompt. Thats why I think the above approach will not work for me.

Comment: Then I don't think it's possible. Even the OpenSSH banner isn't a standard. It's only supported by the OpenSSH client as far as I know, at least it doesn't work with Putty or ConnectBot (Android). Normal interaction starts only after authentication. You could set a banner like "by logging in you accept the agreement" but as I said the banner is not supported in all clients.

Comment: Windows have that login banner and only if you accept it , it prompts you for username/password. Something similar is not available in Linux ?

Comment: I don't think so. I have searched a bit but I haven't seen anything like it. That's why I think the script is the best option. It will execute right after login and the user can't do anything until they accept.

Comment: Thanks Louis. I understand your point. BUt I dont want to prompt for password itself or execute after login until they accept the policy.

Comment: @user3516942 Does Windows do this when you use ssh to log in to Windows? I would be surprised it it does, but if so, please describe in detail in your question.